# Update records in Postgres where timestamp is in a certain range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update a column in a table where the type of the records is `timestamp`
in the form of `2005-01-01 00:00:00`.

Now I am trying to substitute those records with just the year. For example `2005-01-01 00:00:00` would be just `2005`

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE download 
SET download_date = 2005 
WHERE download_date BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2005-01-01 00:00:00') 
                  AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2005-12-31 23:59:59')
```

but I get the following error:

> **invalid input syntax for type double precision: "2005-01-01 00:00:00"**

How could I solve this problem? How can I change it?

Comment: if the datatype of that column is timestamp you got to set it to  timestamp value

Comment: @eshirvana do you mean that I should write something like this TO_TIMESTAMP('2005')?

Comment: then you have to add a new column as int and save the year , otherwise its really not clear what you are trying to achive

Comment: `2005` is not a valid timestamp. You can't set a `timestamp` column to that value. If you only want to store a year, then use an `integer` column

Comment: If you use `to_timestamp()` you will need to specify a format : `TO_TIMESTAMP('2005', '%Y')` which will get you something like `2005-01-01 00:00:00-08`. The offset will depend on your `TimeZone` setting. Probably best to just do `SET download_date = '2005-01-01'` if want to maintain in a `timestamp` field. Otherwise, as mentioned, you will need a separate `integer` field.

Comment: Actually it would be easier to do `SET download_date = date_trunc('year', download_date)`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver perfect, it worked!